# Rename subkey in json output

Tags: fluentd

Is it possible to rename a subkey in JSON or add a new subkey?

For example, I have this log output:

```json
{
    "kubernetes": {
        "pod_name": "kube-apiserver-tst",
        "namespace_name": "kube-system",
        "pod_id": "93a2b43a-46e6-4539-8674-06dede2619fa",
        "labels": {
            "component": "kube-apiserver",
            "tier": "control-plane"
        }
}
```

I know that with `record_transformer` I can add a new key:

```xml
<record>
  pod_labels "something ..."
</record>
```

but it seems that it can only create a new key at the root of JSON:

```json
{
    "kubernetes": {
        "pod_name": "kube-apiserver-tst",
        "namespace_name": "kube-system",
        "pod_id": "93a2b43a-46e6-4539-8674-06dede2619fa",
        "labels": {
            "component": "kube-apiserver",
            "tier": "control-plane"
        }
    "pod_labels": "something ..."
}
```

But can I make it look like this?

```json
{
    "kubernetes": {
        "pod_name": "kube-apiserver-tst",
        "namespace_name": "kube-system",
        "pod_id": "93a2b43a-46e6-4539-8674-06dede2619fa",
        "labels": {
            "component": "kube-apiserver",
            "tier": "control-plane"
        }
        "pod_labels": {
            "component": "kube-apiserver",
            "tier": "control-plane"
        }
}
```

or this:

```json
{
    "kubernetes": {
        "pod_name": "kube-apiserver-tst",
        "namespace_name": "kube-system",
        "pod_id": "93a2b43a-46e6-4539-8674-06dede2619fa",
        "pod_labels": {
            "component": "kube-apiserver",
            "tier": "control-plane"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON is not valid. A closing curly brace is missing.

Here's the valid JSON:

```json
{
    "kubernetes": {
        "pod_name": "kube-apiserver-tst",
        "namespace_name": "kube-system",
        "pod_id": "93a2b43a-46e6-4539-8674-06dede2619fa",
        "labels": {
            "component": "kube-apiserver",
            "tier": "control-plane"
        }
    }
}
```

Minified JSON (`echo '{JSON}' | jq -c .`):

```json
{"kubernetes":{"pod_name":"kube-apiserver-tst","namespace_name":"kube-system","pod_id":"93a2b43a-46e6-4539-8674-06dede2619fa","labels":{"component":"kube-apiserver","tier":"control-plane"}}}
```

---

The [record_transformer](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer) filter plugin can be used with Ruby support (via [enable_ruby](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer#enable_ruby) option) to manipulate an existing key and then the unwanted keys can be removed with its [remove_keys](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer#remove_keys) option.

Here's the sample config:

```xml
<filter debug.test>
  @type         record_transformer
  enable_ruby   true
  <record>
    temp        ${ l = record["kubernetes"]["labels"]; record["kubernetes"]["pod_labels"] = l; nil; }
  </record>
  remove_keys   temp, $.kubernetes.labels
</filter>
```

---

Here's the complete test:

**fluent.conf**

```xml
<source>
  @type       forward
</source>

<filter debug.test>
  @type         record_transformer
  enable_ruby   true
  <record>
    temp        ${ l = record["kubernetes"]["labels"]; record["kubernetes"]["pod_labels"] = l; nil; }
  </record>
  remove_keys   temp, $.kubernetes.labels
</filter>

<match debug.test>
  @type       stdout
</match>
```

Start `fluentd` with this config:

```sh
fluentd -c fluent.conf
```

On another terminal, send an event with `fluent-cat` (`echo '{JSON}' | fluent-cat debug.test`):

```sh
echo '{"kubernetes":{"pod_name":"kube-apiserver-tst","namespace_name":"kube-system","pod_id":"93a2b43a-46e6-4539-8674-06dede2619fa","labels":{"component":"kube-apiserver","tier":"control-plane"}}}' | fluent-cat debug.test
```

In `fluentd` logs, you should see the desired output:

```
2022-02-16 23:08:25.919967225 +0500 debug.test: {"kubernetes":{"pod_name":"kube-apiserver-tst","namespace_name":"kube-system","pod_id":"93a2b43a-46e6-4539-8674-06dede2619fa","pod_labels":{"component":"kube-apiserver","tier":"control-plane"}}}
```

Formatted output with `jq` (`echo '{JSON}' | jq .`):

```sh
echo '{"kubernetes":{"pod_name":"kube-apiserver-tst","namespace_name":"kube-system","pod_id":"93a2b43a-46e6-4539-8674-06dede2619fa","pod_labels":{"component":"kube-apiserver","tier":"control-plane"}}}' | jq .
```

Output:

```json
{
  "kubernetes": {
    "pod_name": "kube-apiserver-tst",
    "namespace_name": "kube-system",
    "pod_id": "93a2b43a-46e6-4539-8674-06dede2619fa",
    "pod_labels": {
      "component": "kube-apiserver",
      "tier": "control-plane"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't know how to do it =) Accepted