# Is if record.dig exists else null exclude even possible?

Tags: ruby, fluentd

I'm trying to work on filtering data in fluentd using the `record_modifier` plugin which are null by adding an if statement. I’ve seen a few examples but none match my use case. Has anyone come across this or can confirm it's even possible?

**Human readable action**

```
partOf = 
if the value of record.dig("kubernetes", "labels", "app.kubernetes.io/part-of") exists 
  include record and value
else
  remove_keys partOf
```

Example config with `dig`:

```xml
<filter **>
  @type record_modifier
  <record>
    partOf ${record.dig("kubernetes", "labels", "app.kubernetes.io/part-of")}
  </record>
</filter>
```

partOf is a common k8s label sample; `"app.kubernetes.io/part-of": "kube-state-metrics",`

Comment: Please add a sample input message in your question. What do you get as the value of `partOf` if it doesn't exist in your current configuration?

Comment: done, added a sample

Comment: Good. The `partOf` should only be added if the KV pair exists, right?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: For example, for this log `{"kubernetes":{"pod_name":"kube-apiserver-tst","namespace_name":"kube-system","pod_id":"93a2b43a-46e6-4539-8674-06dede2619fa","labels":{"component":"kube-apiserver","tier":"control-plane","app.kubernetes.io/part-of": "test"}}}`, the result will be `{"kubernetes":{"pod_name":"kube-apiserver-tst","namespace_name":"kube-system","pod_id":"93a2b43a-46e6-4539-8674-06dede2619fa","labels":{"component":"kube-apiserver","tier":"control-plane","app.kubernetes.io/part-of":"test"},"partOf":"test"}}`, right?

Comment: exactly why I'm using the dig and record_modifier 
  "kubernetes": {
    "pod_name": "kube-prometheus-",
    "namespace_name": "ksm",
    "labels": {
      "app.kubernetes.io/component": "metrics",
      "app.kubernetes.io/name": "kube-state-metrics",
      "app.kubernetes.io/part-of": "kube-state-metrics",
      "app.kubernetes.io/version": "2.3.0",
      "helm.sh/chart": "kube-state-metrics-4.4.3",
      "pod-template-hash": "00000",
      
    }

Comment: I've just posted an answer. It's a bit similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71129267/rename-subkey-in-json-output).

Answer (score 0):

With [record_modifier](https://github.com/repeatedly/fluent-plugin-record-modifier), it's working with embedded Ruby logic like this:

```xml
<filter **>
  @type         record_modifier
  remove_keys   __dummy__
  <record>
    __dummy__   ${ p = record["kubernetes"]["labels"]["app.kubernetes.io/part-of"]; p.nil? ? p : record['partOf'] = p; }
  </record>
</filter>
```

See: https://github.com/repeatedly/fluent-plugin-record-modifier#ruby-code-trick-for-complex-logic

For running a complete test cycle, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71147247/7670262).